# Change which key is primary and which secondary (need to hold Shift to access)

Tags: x11, keyboard-layout

So I have a standard American (English) QWERTY keyboard and was wondering if there was a way I could have some keys act as if I were holding the shift key on them. The main keys I would like to do this is the keys with `[`, `]`, `,` and `.` so that when I press those keys, instead of those showing up, I would like `{`, `}`, `<` and `>` to show up instead. If I hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and press those keys the originals would appear.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS if that's relevant. If this isn't possible does anyone know of a way to do this in just code::blocks as a secondary option? Because that is the main program I need it for.

Comment: Have a look at xkb (setxkbmap, xkbcomp,  etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I guess [this gentoo wiki article](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout_switching), part "Custom keymap" does pretty what you asked about.

In short:

Create a *.map file (use /usr/share/keymaps for an example or consider one below, let's accept, that you created a file called key.map

```
include "us.map"     
keycode  40 = slash            question
keycode  53 = apostrophe       quotedbl
```

zip the map file with gzip

```
gzip key.map
```

Move the file to /usr/share/keymaps/

To find the key codes run dumpkeys or showkey:

`sudo dumpkeys -l`

`sudo showkey`